# SugarCRM C# - getting 404 not found

Tags: c#, web-services, sugarcrm

I'm currently trying to work with the SugarCRM Soap/WSDL from Visual Studio in C#. Whenever I make a call to the service I get a 404 - not found exception back, although I can perfectly add the service when entering the URL in Visual Studio.

My code is as follows:

```
public void Login()
{
    //Create an authentication object
    user_auth user = new user_auth();

    //Set the credentials
    user.user_name = "myusername";
    user.password = this.computeMD5String("mypass");

    //Try to authenticate
    set_entry_result authentication_result = this.sugarService.login(user, "");

    //Check for errors
    if (Convert.ToInt32(authentication_result.error.number) != 0)
    {
        //An error occured
        this.Session = String.Concat(authentication_result.error.name, ": ",
        authentication_result.error.description);

        //Clear the existing sessionId
        this.Session = String.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        //Set the sessionId
        this.Session = authentication_result.id;

        //Clear the existing error
        this.Error = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Have anyone experienced this before? :-)

Any help/hint is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

/ Bo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using one of these url substituting your domain. Also add directory if not installed at root.

http://mydomain/service/v2/soap.php?wsdl or http://mydomain/service/v2_1/soap.php?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

You hav to use the URL 
http://myCRMdomain.com/soap.php?wsdl